# Crystal reports SQL Expression to extract Year from a DateTime column

Tags: sql, visual-studio, datetime, crystal-reports

I'm very new to Crystal Reports and how SQL Expressions work.

But I need to make an SQL Expression to show only the year instead of the full DateTime, for example the field in Crystal Reports shows:

**01/01/2000**

I want an SQL Expression in Crystal Reports that shows the DateTime as:

**2000**

My column is called: `"Film"."ReleaseDate"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{fn YEAR("Film"."ReleaseDate")}